# Image of $\Omega$ under a random variable is atmost countable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I just read this in my text book and I have no idea how to prove it:

> Even if the state space $T$ is not countable, the image $T'$ of $\Omega$ under a random variable is either finite of countably infinite.

Can somebody please give me an idea how to prove this? Thank you so much!

Comment: You cannot prove it becaus it is wrong. Let $X:[0,1]\to[0,1],x\mapsto x$ be a random variable (with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$). Its image is obviously not countable.

Comment: Most likely there are more assumptions that go into that paragraph, such as assumptions about additional properties of $\Omega$ and $T$. Perhaps it is assumed $\Omega$ is countable in this case.  I also do not know what "state space $T$" refers to in this context, or how it relates to $\Omega$ and to the random variable. The key thing is to note (as in the first comment) that what you are asking to prove cannot be proven from the information you provide.

Comment: I see, I must misunderstand the text book! I should check it again. Thank you so much